# how can I create a company logo using blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I tried to find out how I can create a logo for my local company called AMAHORO for employed people using blender.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean logo?

Comment: Start with these two tutorials, they'll probably get you in the right direction:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeKhH1aaXuM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cyUupgsQl0
http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-make-metallic-text/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a text in blender, I would recommend using blender cycles. Then you would need to add a font to it by downloading a free for commercial use font from dafont.com. Then you need to add materials, and etc and animate it. There are many tutorials on google that teach you how. But remember, I would highly recommend making a logo in cycles because the graphics are much better and accurate in lighting.